# Use output of a bash command as an input to environment variable in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In VSCode launch configuration for python, I set environment variables using the env element, like this:

```
"env": {
            "SOME_VARIABLE" : "SOME_VALUE"
}
```

I want to set the value of this environment variable to the result of a bash command, like it is done in command line this way:

```
export SOME_VARIABLE="SOME_VALUE_FROM_$(some command)"
```

Any idea how to do this in launch.json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hisham, I'm the author of the extension. Unfortunately such a feature isn't supported at this state.

Comment: Thanks for the response, it is a good extension and I hope to see it expanded.